# runOnUiThread throws an error in android

Tags: android, timer, timertask

What am I doing wrong here?

```
public class AutoTimer extends Timer {

Timer autoRefreshTimer;
TimerTask task;

public AutoTimer(int delay, int period, Context context ) {  //todo add callback as param

    autoRefreshTimer = new Timer();
    createTask(context);
    autoRefreshTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, delay, period);
}   
private void createTask(final Context context) {
    task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
    context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //run callback method from the calling activity
                }
            });

        }
    };
}
```

}

it underlines the runOnUiThread red and give me the following error:
`the method runOnUiThread(new runnable(){}) is undefined for the type new TimerTask(){}`

Answer (score 4):

`runOnUiThread`is a method of Activity class. Needs a Context.

```
MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
```

If you have the code in non Activity class you will need a Activity context passed to the constructor of the non activity class. Then you can use the same.

Comment: Oh I have passed a context to my timer class, but it wants me to CAST it, however I am trying to make a timer class that I can call from anywhere. My idea is that you pass the timer class a callback function that it then executes on the UI thread.

Comment: @Zapnologica you need `MainActivity mContext = context` then `mContext.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()`. coz `runOnUithread` is a method of activity class

Comment: @Zapnologica you can use interface as a call back to the activity the n update ui in activity itself. However i have not tried that